# Where is python exec?

Tags: python, python-2.7, eval

I know it is possible to get access to builtin functions with something like:

`object().__reduce__()[0].__globals__["__builtins__"]`

And this seems to work for most functions. However, I cannot seem to be able to find `exec()`. I am pretty certain it is a builtin function, so why wouldn't it appear in `__builtins__`? Both `eval()` and `execfile()` are there.

I am using python 2.7

## [EDIT]

A much simpler way to get to globals is with the builtin function `globals()` :) So the above can be reduced to:
`globals()['__builtins__'].__dict__`

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: I understand how this looks suspicious :). It is so I can obfuscate proprietary code. I know it won't be impossible to figure out, but it won't be easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python 2.x, [`exec` is a statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-exec-statement), not a function:

```
>>> # Python 2.x interpreter
>>> 'exec' in dir(__builtins__)
False
>>> callable(exec)  # This would return True if exec was a function
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    callable(exec)
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

In Python 3.x however, `exec` was [converted into a function](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#removed-syntax):

```
>>> # Python 3.x interpreter
>>> 'exec' in dir(__builtins__)
True
>>> callable(exec)
True
>>>
```

Comment: Is there any way to access it without calling it the conventional way? (in 2.7)

Comment: If not in `__builtins__` where is it? Is there a similar way to call a statement to the one I specified in my question?

Comment: No, there isn't really any meaning to accessing a statement.  It would be like wanting to access `if` or `for` or `return`, it is a language construct that isn't represented by an object.

Comment: Is there any other function that would allow me to execute code from a string? Even if it contained multiple statements?

Comment: Why can't you just use the `exec` statement?  If you really need a function I suppose you could use `def exec_function(*args): exec args`.  Although a better question would maybe be do you really need to execute code from a string in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

`exec` is a *keyword*, like `print`. Therefore it is *not* a function.

You can see this if you attempt to assign to it:

```
>>> print = 3
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print = 3
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> exec = 3
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    exec = 3
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> eval = 3
>>>
```

---

If you're hellbent on calling `exec` without using the word `exec`, you can do something like this:

```
import ctypes

ctypes.pythonapi.PyRun_SimpleString("print 'hello world'")
```

which abuses the CPython API to execute a piece of code (which can be arbitrarily long).

And if you need control over the globals and locals, use `PyRun_String`:

```
Py_file_input = 257 # Include/Python.h
def my_exec(s, _globals, _locals):
    return ctypes.pythonapi.PyRun_String(s, Py_file_input, ctypes.py_object(_globals), ctypes.py_object(_locals))

my_exec("print 3 + 3", globals(), locals())
```

Comment: wow ... didn't know about `ctypes.pythonapi`  (+1 for that).  However, that really doesn't replace `exec` -- I assume that you don't somehow magically gain access to the global and local namespaces the way you can with exec.

Comment: @mgilson: See update. `PyRun_String` gives you globals and locals.

Comment: Here's what I was able to do: http://pastebin.com/VZZ41MN9 (that first line was me making sure `code` wasn't reserved)

Comment: Oh and here's the most shady looking version of `print 'Hello World!'`  (after running it through the program I wrote) http://pastebin.com/vY8fyEL2

Comment: Can't tell if you're using it or not, but `str.encode('zip')` and `str.encode('base64')` are wonderfully efficient obfuscation techniques, especially since you can obfuscate the encoding string itself.

Comment: I am using both of them along with `str.encode("bz2")` and `str.encode("uu")`. It chooses randomly between using each of the compression and ascii encoding algorithms so output looks different each time. I couldn't use `exec()` directly because most decent IDS software flags it. There is a small bug I'm working out in that function though so I just used my alternate one for that demo. I'll comment a pastebin link to my completed program tomorrow.

Comment: Hrm, the fact that you are worrying about IDS software worries me. ... what precisely are you trying to do? Have I just enabled something bad to happen? :P

Comment: @nneonneo Nope. Never fear. I'm 15 years old and would like to get into a decent college, so having something bad on my record wouldn't be desirable. I was just trying to hide code I don't want stolen, but at the same time, I know `eval` can produce a lot of false positives especially in php where `eval(base64_decode(gzinflate([malicious code]))` is all too common. Although I do have an interest in security, I get enough entertainment out of capture the flag games and hackme sites that I don't feel the need to cause any trouble.